# Шанс рандома предмета

Tags: php

Не могу реализовать шанс рандома. Например:

Конфета = 50% что выпадет при рандоме.

Шоколадка = 20% что выпадет при рандоме.

Как реализовать чтобы шанс учитывался при рандоме?
Еще пример:

Сосиска = 100% что выпадет при рандоме - это значит при рандоме 100% мне выпадет сосиска.
Как реализовать?

Comment: А у вас код в ооп стиле?

Comment: А какое отношение вопрос имеет к MySQL ?

Answer (score 1):

Можете попробовать такой вариант (есть возможность делать рандом на несколько предметов сразу):

```
function loot($items) {
    $sum = 0;
    $total_weight = 100;
    $chance = rand(1, $total_weight);
    foreach($items as $item => $weight) {
        $sum += $weight;
        if($sum >= $chance) {
            return $item;
        }
    }
    return "Nothing";
}

print(loot(["candy"=>50]));
print(loot(["chocolate"=>20]));
print(loot(["wurst"=>100]));
print(loot(["a"=>50,"b"=>50]));
```

Comment: Название функции выбрано хорошо ))

Comment: "есть возможность делать рандом на несколько предметов сразу", однако вернуться может только один предмет

Comment: @СемушинСергей Ну да. Если нужно, чтобы выпало либо A, либо B - то смотрите последний пример. Либо можно нарандомить их отдельно (как первые три примера)

Comment: @СемушинСергей ,  там нет рекурсии, если вы думаете на неё. *А* помещается в диапазон рандома 1-50, *B* - в 51-100

Comment: @СемушинСергей , сделал демо на js https://jsfiddle.net/br3t/7waf2d86/ , алгоритм не менял

Comment: Извиняюсь, действительно я ступил)

Comment: @СемушинСергей Бывает :)

Answer (score 0):

Хм, могу предложить Вам использовать if-else, как **вариант**.
К примеру, rand у нас от 1 до 10.

```
$chance = rand(1,10);

if($chance == 1 or $chance == 2){
    echo $chocolate;
}else if($chance >= 3 and $chance <= 5){
    echo $candy;
}
```

И так далее.

Comment: спасибо за помощь. но elseif = много когда придется использовать..